# Typedef of a nested class

Tags: c++, typedef, nested-class

Is this the correct way to typedef an inner class in C++?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    struct A
    {
        typedef bool Type;
    };

    struct B
    {
        typedef int Type;
    };

    typedef struct Foo::nested;
};
```

The code compiles under  Visual Studio 2008 but I'm not sure if it is indeed a typedef of a nested class, or whether the standard permits it.

Comment: No, this doesn't compile. Please check what you posted.

Comment: What do you hope it means?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to have another name for the `int` or `bool` types?

Comment: @mydogisbox this is a MWE. My actual code is a lot more complex.

Comment: @Mat please refer to the edited post.

Comment: @Mat Strangely enough it compiles for me using VS2010 32bit

Comment: What is `nested` supposed to refer to? GCC and CLANG are quite certain it doesn't name a type in Foo, and even if it did, that typedef wouldn't declare a new name, so it would be quite pointless.

Comment: Whoops .... doesn't compile with gcc 4.5.3 in the Cygwin environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are after.  If you'd like to typedef one of the existing nested structures, try:

```
typedef struct Foo::A nested;
```

Most likely you want to place the typedef outside of the `Foo` struct in this case -- you can already access `A` from within.

If you wanted to create a typedef inside `Foo` for a nested type of another struct, you could do this:

```
typedef struct Bar::nested myNested;
```

Then you can refer to it as Foo::myNested from outside as well, as long as you declared the typedef public.

Comment: If possible, I'm trying create a typedef for the inner classes of a given class -- just like it is possible to have a typedef for all methods of a class.

Comment: You cannot typedef a member function.  Other than that, what I wrote does exactly what you say you need.  You could write `typedef Foo::A::Type AType;` as well if that's what you want

Comment: Thanks. I meant pointers to member functions, not member functions. I had the hair-brained idea of collecting all the inner classes in a map and using a key in order to retrieve them.

Comment: You cannot access the _types_ at runtime, so unless you are doing some template magic, your map idea will not work (you could use `typeid` to access information about the type at runtime, if that's what you want)